# Do I need a transit visa as a Turkish citizen (with EEA permit) to transit from London Stansted?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, turkish-citizens

I am a Turkish citizen who is studying in Germany (with EEA residence permit & studium visa). I need to attend a conference in Toulouse, France and many of the flights are connected to London.

My departing flight from London Stansted is at 6:50pm on the same day.

Therefore, I need to know if I would need a transit visa (DATV) from UK. As far as I know, RyanAir does not do transit flight so I'll have to re check-in for the next flight. Which means I'll have to pass border control.

I know that a regular Turkish citizen would have to apply for a DATV in these conditions, but what if I have a common format residence format from Germany (with 4 months left on it, but it will be renewed).

Here is what is written in many of the other posts as requirements:

> **You might be eligible for the ‘transit without visa concession’ if**:
>
> you arrive and depart by air
>
> have a confirmed onward flight which leaves within 24 hours
>
> have the right documents for your destination
>
> **One of the following must also apply**:
>
> […]
>
> you have a valid uniform format residence permit issued by an EEA
>   state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need a visa, as stated by the quoted document.

At border control at Stansted, present your passport, residence permit card, filled out landing card (blue form you get on the plane or before border control) and your connecting ticket to Toulouse

Also, there is no way to transit without clearing border control at Stansted, as there is no "international connections" path.

Comment: @mozcelikors The Ryanair boarding passes are printed in advance, so to be clear: put the residence card, landing card and the boarding pass FROM London "sandwiched" at the passport's ID page